# Move Discussion To Chat More Preemptively?

Tags: feature-request

I know I can type `[chat]` in a comment and it will link to the chat rooms in general. I also know that, after a lot of back-and-forth in comments, a link will come up to `Move this discussion to chat` that will create a new chat with the comment history and link to it.

It would be nice to be able to type something like `[move this conversation to chat]` that would have the same effect as the link, namely it creates a chat and links to the original question with the comment thread copied in for context.

- Is there a feature like that?
- Is it possible to request one?
- Do others here want it?

Comment: You know, until you posted this, I didn't realize that a permanent link holds the comment history. I've frequently avoided going to chat for fear that what was exchanged would be lost for others to read or, for that matter, join in and contribute to it. I'll add that no, I don't feel a need for the feature.